# Include Mono homebrew package in Cmake on mac

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, mono, build-system

I'm trying to embed the Mono runtime in a C++ application. I installed Mono using homebrew(I use mac), and now I'm trying to include & link it with CMake.

```
include_directories(/usr/local/Cellar/mono/6.12.0.122/include/mono-2.0/)
```

Including the headers with this line of CMake works fine, but linking with this line does not.

```
target_link_libraries(Alchem /usr/local/Cellar/mono/6.12.0.122/lib/)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also, what is the right way of doing this? Hardcoding paths like this is not very platform independant, so what is the correct way of including Mono that works cross platform out of the box?

Edit: I've also tried [this](https://github.com/sidch/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindMono.cmake) cmake findMono script, but it doesn't work with mac.

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" - You pass a **directory** to the `target_link_libraries`, but it expects a library **file**.

Comment: Thank you! @Tsyvarev ! However, in /usr/local/Cellar/mono/6.12.0.122/lib/, there are a million different .a and .dylib files, and I have no idea which to link. I've tried libmono-2.0.a, and that seems to have done something, but it still has undefined symbols. Is there a way of linking all of the files in a directory?